# The entity type is not part of the model for the current context (autofac)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, autofac

I have an issue with EntityFramework at the moment.
I added some new Entities to my database context, one of them was **Client**. Here is my **DbContext** with the new entries:

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{

    //Define our tables
    public DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HealthCheck> HealthChecks { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClientClaim> ClientClaims { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClientSecret> ClientSecrets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Consent> Consents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Scope> Scopes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ScopeClaim> ScopeClaims { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public DatabaseContext(CormarConfig config) : base(config.SqlConnectionString)
    {

        // Write our SQL to the debug window
        Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);

        // Disable Lazy Loading
        base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        // TODO: Remove when publishing!
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overrides the inherited OnModelCreated method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelBuilder">The DbModelBuilder</param>
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        // Rename tables
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Message>().ToTable("Messages");

        // Create our foreign key
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasMany(m => m.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.RoleId);

        // Create our primary keys
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(m => m.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(m => m.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(m => new { m.RoleId, m.UserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Setting>().HasKey(m => new { m.Id, m.Name });

        //modelBuilder.Entity<RefreshToken>().Property(t => t.Subject).HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_SubjectClient", 0) { IsUnique = true }));
        //modelBuilder.Entity<RefreshToken>().Property(t => t.ClientId).HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_SubjectClient", 1) { IsUnique = true }));            
    }
}
```

I have run `add-migration` and `update-database` and can see that my new entity tables have been created.
I then created a simple class that should exposes **Clients**, it looks like this:

```
public class IdentityServerClientStore : IClientStore
{
    private readonly DbSet<Client> _clients;

    public IdentityServerClientStore(DbContext context)
    {
        _clients = context.Set<Client>();
    }

    public async Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId) => await _clients.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ClientId.Equals(clientId));
}
```

This is injected using **Autofac** and is registered like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<DatabaseContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<IdentityServerClientStore>().As<idsrv.IClientStore>().InstancePerDependency();
```

But when I try to do anything, I get this error:

> "The entity type Client is not part of the model for the current context."

The whole stack trace looks like this:

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The entity type Client is not part of the model for the current context.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)\r\n   at Cormar.Business.Identity.IdentityServerClientStore.<FindClientByIdAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\JaymieJeffrey\\Documents\\GitHub\\Cormar\\Cormar.Business\\Identity\\IdentityServerClientStore.cs:line 18\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.ClientSecretValidator.<ValidateAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Validation\\ClientSecretValidator.cs:line 63\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController.<ProcessAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Endpoints\\Connect\\TokenEndpointController.cs:line 98\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController.<Post>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Endpoints\\Connect\\TokenEndpointController.cs:line 74\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.System.Web.Http910911.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Configuration\\Hosting\\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Configuration\\Hosting\\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Configuration\\Hosting\\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Configuration\\Hosting\\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Configuration\\Hosting\\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Configuration\\Hosting\\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Configuration\\Hosting\\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Configuration\\Hosting\\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Configuration\\Hosting\\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Configuration\\Hosting\\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Configuration\\Hosting\\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in c:\\ballen\\github\\identity\\IdSrv3\\IdentityServer3\\source\\Core\\Configuration\\Hosting\\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0"
}
```

Can anyone guess why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you show your `Client` class?

Comment: It's part of IdentityServer3

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add this to your OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().ToTable("Client");
```

Comment: that's only needed if I want to rename a automatically generated table is it not? If I do that, it will rename the table "Clients" to "Client".

Comment: You're defining the DbSet property name as Clients (plural). If your table name were plural that would work fine. But, the error is stating that Client (singular) is not part of the current context. I believe is you add the line above it should work for you.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work. I still get the same error :(